# Access instance function pointer in base template

Tags: c++, templates, boost-bind

I am inheriting from a base template class and need to override the `onConnect` method in my derived template class. How can I ensure that the method called in the second `bind` is overridden method from the derived template instance?

Here is the snippet from the base template class.

```
class connector()
{ 
 typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator resolver_type;

 void start();
 void onConnect(const boost::system::error_code& ec, resolver_type::iterator i);
 void connectCondition(const boost::system::error_code& ec, resolver_type::iterator i);
};
void Connector::start(){
    async_connect(socket, i, 
      boost::bind(&Connector::connectCondition, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::iterator),
      boost::bind(&Connector::onConnect, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
}
void Connector::connectCondition(const boost::system::error_code& ec, resolver_type::iterator i)
{
  // test connection
}
void Connector::onConnect(const boost::system::error_code& ec, resolver_type::iterator i)
{
  std::cout << "called onConnect from base template class << std::endl; 
}
```

Currently this code will always invoke the `onConnect` method from the base template class rather than the derived template class.

```
class DerivedConnector : public Connector
{
 typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator resolver_type;
 //use base connector start method
 void start();
 //override onConnect
 void onConnect(const boost::system::error_code& ec, resolver_type::iterator i);
};

void DerivedConnector::start()
{
  std::cout << "Calling base start method" << std::endl;
  Controller::start();
}
void DerivedConnector::onConnect(const boost::system::error_code& ec, resolver_type::iterator i)
{
  std::cout << "called onConnect from derived template class" << std::endl;
}
```

I have tried using `this->onConnect` to no avail as the compiler complains about unmatched function call.

Comment: You are not showing any declarations. How do you want anyone do know anything about what happens in your code?

Comment: You need your function to be `virtual`.